# Why am I getting an error while doing fetchAll for an array with parse.com?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have an object Enquiry which has a one to many relation with History objects.

My requirement is that when user asks for history I need to fetchAll the history objects and then display them

Here is my code:

```
function fetchAndShowHistory(object, objectType) {
  var historyObjects = object.get("history");
  Parse.Object.fetchAll(historyObjects, {
    success : function(historyObjects) {
      //code to show history objects
    },
    error : function(error) {
      alert("Could not fetch history, " + error.message);
    },
  });
}
```

Now with this current code I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,d){if(c.isString(a))return
>   b.Object.create.apply(this,arguments);a=a||{},d&&d.parse&&(a=this.parse(a));var
>   e=b.getValue(this,"defaults");if(e&&(a=c.extend({},e,a)),d&&d.collection&&(this.collection=d.collect......l'

Note that this doesn't even make the call to the server but dies in the javascript code. Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure historyObjects is a list after object.get("history") ? Put a breakpoint or console.log there to be certain.

Comment: historyObjects is an array of history objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ',' on the 2nd-last line of your code.  This is a syntax error and will cause your code to fail.

This is the correct code ->

```
function fetchAndShowHistory(object, objectType) {
  var historyObjects = object.get("history");
  Parse.Object.fetchAll(historyObjects, {
    success : function(historyObjects) {
        //code to show history objects
    },
    error : function(error) {
        alert("Could not fetch history, " + error.message);
    }
});
```